# How do I hide images in a row with html/css/bootstrap4?

Tags: image, bootstrap-4

I want to display 6 images (3 images on row 1, and 3 on row 2) on a page on which I am using the Bootstrap 4 grid. I currently have a total of 9 images on page, but I want the 3 images on row 3 to be hidden.

In other words, I just want the 6 images to show on the page instead. If the user would click the button related to illustrations, the 3 images on row 3 will show on the page. I know that the display:none css property will hide the images. However, the images do not show up if user clicks on the button. How do I achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: Could you provide us with a sample of your HTML? Also do you want a pure CSS solution or do you want a solution that uses JavaScript? And what do you mean by "the button related to the illustrations"? How is it related to it?